# Wordpress Curl based Login - Session Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I have a application running on Codeigniter on

https://example1.com

I have installed wordpress on

https://example1/com/blog

When user register on https://example1.com, i have created the same user in WordPress also

Now when user login to my https://example1.com by default i need them login to my blog also

I used CURL to achieve this.

I am able to login to WordPress blog successfully

But when i click on any menus WordPress session is expired

My Code

```
                    $rredirecturl = https://example1.com/blog;
                    $curl = curl_init();

                    //---------------- generic cURL settings start ----------------
                    $header     = array(
                        "Accept: */*",
                        "Referer:https://example1.com/blog/wp-login.php",
                        "Origin: https://example1.com/blog",
                        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        "Connection: Keep-Alive",
                        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                        "Pragma: no-cache",
                        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15"
                    );
          

                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15');
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');

                    $url = 'https://example1.com/blog/wp-login.php';
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
                    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'log='.urlencode($get_username).'&pwd='.urlencode($password).'&redirect_to='.urlencode($rredirecturl));
                    
                    $result = curl_exec ($curl);
                    curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Why are you setting CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to an empty string?

Comment: I have added cookie.txt file then i removed , Either way the same issue exists